# How to fix Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type... Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following helper method

```
distance :: Segment -> Length
distance ((ax, ay), (bx, by)) = sqrt ((bx-ax)^2 + (by-ay)^2)
```

And I get the warning

```
polycake.hs:115:46: Warning:
Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type ‘Integer’
  (Integral b0) arising from a use of ‘^’ at polycake.hs:115:46
  (Num b0) arising from the literal ‘2’ at polycake.hs:115:47
In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘(bx - ax) ^ 2’
In the first argument of ‘sqrt’, namely
  ‘((bx - ax) ^ 2 + (by - ay) ^ 2)’
In the expression: sqrt ((bx - ax) ^ 2 + (by - ay) ^ 2)
```

I can't suppress the warning either, looking for a way to explicitly cast it to a type.

Comment: Do you understand why you're getting the warning? This is the sort of problem where understanding how it arises is about 99% of solving it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Annotate each `2`, as in

```
(bx-ax)^(2 :: Integer)
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense